# Samsung Glaxy S4 users report that BOOT_COMPLETED receiver won't work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

Well one of my apps on the play store have a `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver and it have never got any issue until the S4, I have received multiple emails from S4 users saying that the app isn't working and after some troubleshooting the `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver is not getting called.

Does anyone here know how to fix this for this particular device?

Here's the main code of it:

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        ...
        ...
        //ALL MY CODE IS HERE
        ...
        ...
    }
}
}
```

Manifest :

```
    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Of course I have the correct permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Did the users run an activity of yours? Remember that, until something manually runs a component of your app, manifest-registered receivers will not work, on Android 3.1+.

Comment: Yes they did, they opened it and made some troubleshooting that I was asking them to do. All the results end with the same result, the receiver isn't being called at boot so the user have to open the app again to enable the services.

Comment: You might also take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221679/boot-completed-intent-not-received-on-all-devices/17221917#17221917 where I was discussing this sort of thing with somebody else yesterday, in case it gives you any clues. I don't have an S4 at present, so I don't know if there are any other specifics for it with regards to `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Comment: Interesting, will try with this one to see if I got something. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I just picked up an S4, and I had no problem with `BOOT_COMPLETED`, using this test project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot Note, though, that there are several device models marketed as the Galaxy S4.

Comment: Could you try out my app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rotaryheart.su.root.tools you can email me so that I can tell you what to do to test it (you don't need to be rooted).